# scroll link change to top link when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to put a link on my webpage that when it first loads is used to scroll the page down by 500px. If the page is scrolled 10px from the top i would like that link to become a back to top link. I have coded what I thought would be correct but the link appears to only link to the top. It changes from a down chevron to an up chevron when the user scrolls but it does not then reset when the page is back to the top. hope this makes sense.

HTML

```
<a class="w-toplink active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
```

CSS

```
.w-toplink {
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: -50px;
right: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
padding:12px;
line-height: 48px;
height: 28px;
width: 35px;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
transition: background-color 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, bottom 0.3s;
background-color: #333;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
color: #fff;
opacity:0; 
transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
}

.w-toplink.active {
bottom: 30px;
opacity: 0.7;
}

.w-toplink:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

.down-link {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
}

#w-downlink i {
    line-height: 42px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#w-downlink {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #191919;
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    right:0;
    margin-right:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.w-downlink:hover {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #191919;
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    right:0;
    margin-right:20px;
     cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.w-toplink

{opacity:0; transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;}
.w-toplink.active{opacity:0.7;}
    .w-toplink:hover{opacity:1;}
```

JQUERY

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollDownLink = $('.w-toplink');
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 5) {
    scrollDownLink.attr('href', '#about');
    scrollDownLink.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa fa-chevron-up');
  } else {
    scrollDownLink.attr('href', '#top-anchor');
    scrollDownLink.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa fa-chevron-up');
  }
});
```

Comment: If your problem is that the chevron isn't changing then take a closer look at your JavaScript code, specifically the second lines in your if and else blocks.

Comment: @LukeK It's that the chevron doesn't reset to a down chevron. In fact the whole link disappears and doesn't appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to test this out and it's quite a simple fix.

This is your code as it is before I made some small change

```
$(window).scroll(function() {


var scrollDownLink = $('.w-toplink');
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 5) {
    scrollDownLink.attr('href', '#about');
    scrollDownLink.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa fa-chevron-up');
  } else {
    scrollDownLink.attr('href', '#top-anchor');
    scrollDownLink.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa fa-chevron-up');
  }
});
```

I changed the if block to

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() < 5) {
    scrollDownLink.attr('href', '#about');
    scrollDownLink.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa fa-chevron-down');
  }
```

It's all working fine now. [Here's a codepen of the working code](http://codepen.io/literallyluke/pen/wWVpvZ)

Note that for it to be triggered on 10px from the top you'll need to also change the 5 to a 10

Comment: That works but it still disappears when the page is page to top. Is there a way of coding two versions of the same link. One that appears at 0px and then changes to the other when the page is scrolled 10px? When the page is back to 0px it changes back?

Comment: You could code two different versions, but it seems unnecessary when you're only changing one thing in it. I'm not able to replicate the link disappearing when page to top. What browser are you using? Is there other code that might interfere with it? Worst I'm getting is that the chevron isn't changing appropriately, but that's because the scroll listener isn't triggered when you jump to a section

Comment: So how would i code chevron down to send the page down and chevron up to send the page up? That's what i can't seem to do?

Comment: I assume you have elements with the top-link and about ids on the page somewhere? If so then it should work fine for jumping up and down the page. You might need to add some custom click listeners to change the class between chevron-up and chevron-down when clicked though

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery code to have the functionality without the scrolling messing up with the classes.

The first part manipulates the chevron and the second the scrolling upon click.

```
var scrollDownLink = $('.w-toplink');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 10) {
        scrollDownLink.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa fa-chevron-down');
    } else {
        scrollDownLink.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa fa-chevron-up');
    }
});

scrollDownLink.click(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()>10){
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop:$('#top-anchor').offset().top
        },500);
    }else{
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop:$('#about').offset().top
        },500);
    }
});
```